# Automated upload of a Salesforce file to Box.com record-linked folder

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, box-api, force.com

I have a Box for Salesforce intregration app installed and it works great when a user manually adds a file to a SFDC record. I have an Apex class that creates a PDF file that needs to be linked to a SFDC record. I am able to upload the record through the box-api to an existing folder that is linked to the record. But I cannot figure out an automated way to create a folder that is linked to a SFDC record.

Did anyone find a solution to this scenario?

Thanks,
Jose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't currently have a public API to tag a folder such that it's linked to a Salesforce record. While we have a private API method to do so in V1, we are no longer sharing that because it will be deprecated at the end of the year. We hope to include a new version with our V2 API in the public documentation soon. Keep an eye out for it here: http://developers.box.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately we will have to create our own solution. I was hoping to be able to use Box.com.